# SSIS Loading data from csv file to sql table

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am loading data from csv file to my sql table through SSIS. Is there any default limit specified on number of records to be read from csv file ?

While loading the csv file, my data flow component is processing only 5000 records, though it contains 5341 records,as shown in the image below.How can i fix this ?

[image]

Comment: i see there is error output, is that possible the rest of data was redirected to the error log table?

Comment: @LONG: I checked my error log table..its empty

Comment: my bad, if it has, it will show the how many like the imported ones. Did you check the flat file source connection manager, is there any number of rows skipped in your source connection manager? As far as I know, the number of records that flat file source would be far more than 5000.

Comment: Nope. DataRowsToSkip property is already set to '0'

Comment: And HeaderRowsToSkip? 0 As well?

Comment: When you look at the results in your staging table, which rows from the file are not in it?   The last 341?   Or are they interspersed throughout the file?

Comment: @Tyron78: Yes HeaderRowsToSkip =>0

Answer (score 0):

Are you [mistakenly] swallowing error rows?

[image: Error Output]

What have you got set in the **source** error output?